# Error when attempting to use the heap

Tags: c++, memory, dynamic, heap-memory, stack-memory

I've written a program that works for most input, but if I ask it to make a increase precision by using a larger array (about 320x320 was when I started seeing trouble) it crashes. I searched for my issue online and found [this similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14351313/reading-a-large-file-into-an-array-causes-a-crash) and [this tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/) on what to do about it. The problematic part of my original code is below - I had precision=320 and holepop=770.

```
double spacing = 2.0/(precision+1);
int lattice_int[precision][precision];
for (i=0; i<precision; ++i){
    for (ii=0; ii<precision; ++ii){
        mindist_sq = 2.0;
        lattice_int[i][ii] = 0;
        for (iii=0; iii<holepop; ++iii){
            xdist = abs(xcoord[iii] + 1.0 - spacing/2 - spacing*i);
            ydist = abs(ycoord[iii] - 1.0 + spacing/2 + spacing*ii);
            thisdist_sq = xdist*xdist+ydist*ydist;
            if (thisdist_sq < mindist_sq){
                 lattice_int[i][ii] = dint[iii];
                 mindist_sq = thisdist_sq;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to fix it with this change in the first two lines:

```
int * lattice_int;
double spacing = 2.0/(precision+1);
lattice_int = new int[precision][precision];
```

(I also put in "delete lattice_int[][];" at the end.) However, I received this error: 'precision' cannot occur in a constant expression
Is it because I'm trying to work with multiple indices? What can I do to work around my problem? Thank you!

Comment: `int lattice_int[precision][precision];` requires `precision` to be a compile time constant. If you use `new` it does not. Has nothing to do with "multiple indices" aka. multiple dimensions. Edit: You would do `new int[precision * precision];` for the `new` version, instead of `new int[precision][precision];` as @Puppy noticed. Anyway, stick to `std::vector`, much better.

Comment: You're wrong there. If you use `new[]` then only the first dimension may be non-constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `new[]`, it'll only cause you pain, suffering, memory leaks, use-after-frees, etc.

You can use `std::vector` in this respect.

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> lattice_int(precision, std::vector<int>(precision));
```

No memory freeing necessary.

Comment: Thank you! I'll have to look into the difference between vectors and arrays so I know how what to do with each. To be honest, all my programming experience is self-taught and so it has large gaps.

Comment: @BGreen: Arrays are shit. Vectors are not. That's pretty much the main difference.

Answer (score 0):

Your `lattice_int` variable is 2d array. You can allocate it using following code:

```
int precision = 500;
int ** lattice_int;
double spacing = 2.0/(precision+1);

lattice_int = new int*[precision];
for (int i = 0; i < precision; i++)
{
    lattice_int[i] = new int[precision];
}
```

Same way you have to iterate for deletion of each sub array.

Note: This is pure illustration to use pointers for creating two dimensional array. The better way would be to use vector for this.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate that you explained a work-around for how to do it with new[] and pointers as well, just to show how to do it by thinking a little out of the box.

Comment: @BGreen: The box is there for a very important reason. It's because if you stand outside it, you will step on a landmine. Or a hundred. And then your application will be an unreliable buggy piece of crap.

Comment: On the other hand if I never left the box I'd still be at "Hello World." There's a fine line somewhere between trying new things and trying to use what you don't understand.
I get your point, though - you're saying not to use tools in ways that they aren't suitable to be used.I was just trying to show some appreciation for another perspective, even if it was in practice a bad idea.